# Windows Authentication Using Spring MVC + Angular JS

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security, spring-security-kerberos

Using Angular JS for my front-end and Spring MVC for web services. Based on SOA architecture, front end and back end are loosely coupled.

I want to use Windows Authentication to login in the web application without asking any username and password in the login page.

I am getting struck in Spring Security Kerberos and want to authenticate from the LDAP and then Use Spring JWT oAuth protocol to continue further.

Can someone help where am I missing or what will be the robust way for this architecture.

P.S. : Spring MVC + Angular JS

Comment: Hi I am also wanting to do the same, can you please share on how did you achieve the same

Answer (score 0):

High level: If your doing the authentication via the Internet i.e where you don't have access to get Kerberos tickets via Spring Security, you need to consider using SAML or OAuth. Otherwise if you have local access and can talk directly to the authentication servers  from your server hosting your code you can use Kerberos.

SAML and OAuth are very different to LDAP and Kerberos. Kerberos and LDAP can generally only be used if you have direct access to the authentication servers, i.e when are you in the same windows domain.

For further help please post code samples and an outline of what your trying to achieve.

Comment: Here I am targeting only for intranet not for internet  .

Comment: What are you wanting to use OAuth & JWT for then?

Comment: Using JWT for passing token for authorisation